# rm: cannot remove ‘[name].rmanbkp’: Input/output error

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat, rm

I'm using `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)` and have vgroup mount to folder is: `/dev/mapper/vg_oradata-lv_oradata      886G  636G  206G  76% /bak`.
Now, In folder /bak have a some file cannot remove with info:

```
[root@bak bak]# ls -l
ls: cannot access data_t950234427_s4036_p2.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950499092_s4061_p9.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950493620_s4055_p1.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950529442_s4066_p1.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950499092_s4061_p7.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950499092_s4061_p10.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950499092_s4061_p6.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950499096_s4064_p12.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950499096_s4064_p10.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950513219_s4065_p1.rmanbkp: Input/output error
ls: cannot access data_t950493620_s4056_p1.rmanbkp: Input/output error
total 168166396
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950234427_s4036_p2.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950493620_s4055_p1.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950493620_s4056_p1.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950499092_s4061_p10.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950499092_s4061_p6.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950499092_s4061_p7.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950499092_s4061_p9.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950499096_s4064_p10.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950499096_s4064_p12.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950513219_s4065_p1.rmanbkp
-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ? data_t950529442_s4066_p1.rmanbkp
```

When I cannot execute command `rm -rf` its in folder:

```
[root@bak bak]# rm -rf data_t950234427_s4036_p2.rmanbkp
rm: cannot remove ‘data_t950234427_s4036_p2.rmanbkp’: Input/output error
```

What is the problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Either a hardware problem or filesystem corruption (which in turn could be caused by hardware or software errors). Take the system offline, be prepared to restore from backup, run `fsck` on the filesystem and preferably also `badblocks` on the actual disk drive. (The disk is the most likely culprit, but if you're getting this again, it could also be a connector, an interface driver (SATA/RAID/whatever you're using) or even the RAM.)

Comment: check the permissions on the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your storage subsystem is having trouble. Read the output of `dmesg`. Take a look at `lsblk`. Are you using RAID? See `cat /proc/mdstat`.

Comment: when I run command `dmesg` get output is: `[1352255.571188] EXT4-fs error: 1 callbacks suppressed
[1352255.571194] EXT4-fs error (device dm-43): ext4_lookup:1441: inode #2: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 16
[1352255.571836] EXT4-fs error (device dm-43): ext4_lookup:1441: inode #2: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 16` and folder `/bak` is one disk to most folder cannot RAID.

Comment: Now, in folder /bak can save and remove file another but with file permission is `-????????? ? ?      ?                  ?            ?` cannot remove